# What is the best way to implement icon based custom toolbar with Xamarin?

Tags: android, mobile, xamarin, android-actionbar, toolbar

I would like to have a toolbar (actionbar) in my app which looks like the screenshot, basically 4 icons shown on top of the screen with no text:

[image]

What is the best way to implement icon based custom toolbar with Xamarin?

- ActionBar with some special settings
- Custom toolbar layout consisting of 4 image buttons
- Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the new Toolbar widget, with a custom layout, but I would recommend to use a [TabLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) with a ViewPager, instead.

Look at the [material design guidelines](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html) about the use of tabs in Android applications.

Comment: http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsbHJuWi04N0ZIc0E/components_tabs_usage_mobile7.png this one looks exactly as what i want, but not clear on how to get it with xamarin forms.

Comment: If you use Xamarin.Android you will have direct access to Android widgets. Add the NuGet packages for Support Library v4, v7 and Design to access ViewPager, TabLayout and Toolbar. But if you want to go with Xamarin Forms, your options are limited. Look at http://www.patridgedev.com/2015/03/07/xamarin-forms-switching-tabbedpage-tabs-programmatically/. Tabbedpage will allow you to have tabs with icons in IOS, but not in Android.

Answer (score 1):

**Developers are encouraged to build tabbed applications using the ActionBar**. The [ActionBar](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/actionbar/) is available in all version of Android. It was first introduced in Android 3.0 (API level 11) and was back ported to Android 2.2 (API level 8) and Android 2.3 (API level 10) in the v7 appcompat library - available in the Xamarin Component Store.

You can use SetCustomView method to set custom layout for tab item.